# How to set up a while loop based on values in two dataframes (warehouse slotting) in Python?

Tags: python

Warehouse slotting question. I have a 'sorted_location' df that I have sequenced in order that I need to assign to certain products based on their demands:

**sorted_location df:**

```
Label   Slot_Type   Slot_Type_Sequence  Cumulative Pallets  Sequence to Slot
3-10-36-2   6 Deep Bulk 1   11  0
3-10-35-2   6 Deep Bulk 1   22  1
3-10-34-2   6 Deep Bulk 1   33  2
3-10-33-2   6 Deep Bulk 1   44  3
3-10-32-2   6 Deep Bulk 1   55  4
... ... ... ... ... ...
2-9-5-2 1 Deep Prime    5   2579    760
2-9-4-2 1 Deep Prime    5   2580    761
2-9-3-2 1 Deep Prime    5   2581    762
2-9-2-2 1 Deep Prime    5   2582    763
2-9-1-2 1 Deep Prime    5   2583    764
```

**demand df:**

```
    SKU Description Pallets
0   85,072  TITO'S HANDMADE VODKA 1.75LTR   33
1   2,922   VEUVE CLICQUOT BRUT NV  22
2   66,867  DON JULIO 1942 ANEJO TEQ    22
```

I basically need to assign location by 'Slot_Type_Sequence' first (5 different slot types) and then within the slot type I have several locations ('Label', total 764 locations). How do I set up a while loop in such a way that I will get 3 locations assigned for Tito's Vodka (since the Demand is 33 pallets and the first 3 locations can hold 33 pallets)

Any help appreciated!

**Desired output:**

```
Label   SKU Description 
3-10-36-2   85,072 TITO'S HANDMADE VODKA 1.75LTR
3-10-35-2   85,072 TITO'S HANDMADE VODKA 1.75LTR
3-10-34-2   85,072 TITO'S HANDMADE VODKA 1.75LTR
3-10-33-2   2,922  VEUVE CLICQUOT BRUT NV
3-10-32-2   2,922  VEUVE CLICQUOT BRUT NV
```

Edited to add raw data

**sorted_location df (Top 35 locations)**

```
{'Label': {0: '3-10-36-2',
  1: '3-10-35-2',
  2: '3-10-34-2',
  3: '3-10-33-2',
  4: '3-10-32-2',
  5: '3-10-31-2',
  6: '3-10-30-2',
  7: '3-10-29-2',
  8: '3-10-28-2',
  9: '3-10-27-2',
  10: '3-10-25-2',
  11: '3-10-24-2',
  12: '3-10-23-2',
  13: '3-10-22-2',
  14: '3-10-21-2',
  15: '3-10-20-2',
  16: '3-10-19-2',
  17: '3-10-18-2',
  18: '3-10-17-2',
  19: '3-10-16-2',
  20: '3-10-14-2',
  21: '3-10-13-2',
  22: '3-10-12-2',
  23: '3-10-11-2',
  24: '3-10-10-2',
  25: '3-10-9-2',
  26: '3-10-8-2',
  27: '3-10-6-2',
  28: '3-10-5-2',
  29: '3-10-4-2',
  30: '3-10-3-2',
  31: '3-10-2-2',
  32: '3-10-1-2',
  33: '2-4-2-2',
  34: '2-4-3-2'},
 'Slot_Type': {0: '6 Deep Bulk',
  1: '6 Deep Bulk',
  2: '6 Deep Bulk',
  3: '6 Deep Bulk',
  4: '6 Deep Bulk',
  5: '6 Deep Bulk',
  6: '6 Deep Bulk',
  7: '6 Deep Bulk',
  8: '6 Deep Bulk',
  9: '6 Deep Bulk',
  10: '6 Deep Bulk',
  11: '6 Deep Bulk',
  12: '6 Deep Bulk',
  13: '6 Deep Bulk',
  14: '6 Deep Bulk',
  15: '6 Deep Bulk',
  16: '6 Deep Bulk',
  17: '6 Deep Bulk',
  18: '6 Deep Bulk',
  19: '6 Deep Bulk',
  20: '6 Deep Bulk',
  21: '6 Deep Bulk',
  22: '6 Deep Bulk',
  23: '6 Deep Bulk',
  24: '6 Deep Bulk',
  25: '6 Deep Bulk',
  26: '6 Deep Bulk',
  27: '6 Deep Bulk',
  28: '6 Deep Bulk',
  29: '6 Deep Bulk',
  30: '6 Deep Bulk',
  31: '6 Deep Bulk',
  32: '6 Deep Bulk',
  33: '4 Deep Prime',
  34: '4 Deep Prime'},
 'Slot_Type_Sequence': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 1,
  19: 1,
  20: 1,
  21: 1,
  22: 1,
  23: 1,
  24: 1,
  25: 1,
  26: 1,
  27: 1,
  28: 1,
  29: 1,
  30: 1,
  31: 1,
  32: 1,
  33: 2,
  34: 2},
 'Cumulative Pallets': {0: 11,
  1: 22,
  2: 33,
  3: 44,
  4: 55,
  5: 66,
  6: 77,
  7: 88,
  8: 99,
  9: 110,
  10: 121,
  11: 132,
  12: 143,
  13: 154,
  14: 165,
  15: 176,
  16: 187,
  17: 198,
  18: 209,
  19: 220,
  20: 231,
  21: 242,
  22: 253,
  23: 264,
  24: 275,
  25: 286,
  26: 297,
  27: 308,
  28: 319,
  29: 330,
  30: 341,
  31: 352,
  32: 363,
  33: 370,
  34: 377},
 'Sequence to Slot': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  11: 11,
  12: 12,
  13: 13,
  14: 14,
  15: 15,
  16: 16,
  17: 17,
  18: 18,
  19: 19,
  20: 20,
  21: 21,
  22: 22,
  23: 23,
  24: 24,
  25: 25,
  26: 26,
  27: 27,
  28: 28,
  29: 29,
  30: 30,
  31: 31,
  32: 32,
  33: 33,
  34: 34}}
```

**demand df (Top 40 SKUs)**

```
{'SKU': {0: '85,072',
  1: '2,922',
  2: '66,867',
  3: '100,835',
  4: '114,732',
  5: '139,672',
  6: '120,922',
  7: '22,024',
  8: '95,340',
  9: '144,916',
  10: '6,780',
  11: '7,154',
  12: '90,607',
  13: '1,242',
  14: '95,527',
  15: '1,394',
  16: '94,079',
  17: '1,497',
  18: '95,684',
  19: '9,721',
  20: '80,587',
  21: '1,644',
  22: '106,160',
  23: '139,228',
  24: '77,264',
  25: '111,205',
  26: '120,920',
  27: '86,813',
  28: '75,899',
  29: '2,064',
  30: '3,594',
  31: '114,451',
  32: '120,756',
  33: '1,493',
  34: '50,995',
  35: '2,023',
  36: '95,347',
  37: '131,255',
  38: '111,125',
  39: '2,580'},
 'Description': {0: "TITO'S HANDMADE VODKA 1.75LTR",
  1: 'VEUVE CLICQUOT BRUT NV',
  2: 'DON JULIO 1942 ANEJO TEQ',
  3: 'COPPOLA CHARD DIRECTORS',
  4: 'GRUET CUVEE 89 SPARKLING BRUT',
  5: 'WHIP SHOTS VOD INF VAN CRM 200',
  6: 'GRUET CUVEE 89 SPARKLING ROSE',
  7: 'KETEL ONE VODKA 1.75',
  8: 'LA MARCA PROSECCO',
  9: 'DUE WEST CABERNET SAUVIGNON',
  10: 'JOHNNIE WALKER BLUE 750',
  11: 'MAKERS MARK BOURBON 1.75',
  12: 'UNRULY RED',
  13: 'BAILEYS IRISH CREAM',
  14: 'UNRULY CABERNET',
  15: 'PATRON SILVER TEQ',
  16: 'DAOU CABERNET SAUVIGNON',
  17: 'ABSOLUT VODKA 1.75',
  18: 'DON JULIO ANEJO 70TH ANNIV',
  19: 'JAMESON IRISH WHISKEY 1.75',
  20: "TITO'S HANDMADE VODKA 750ML",
  21: 'JACK DAN WHISKEY 1.75L',
  22: 'UNRULY CHARDONNAY',
  23: 'DOM PERIGNON 12',
  24: 'DOLCE VITA PROSECCO',
  25: 'CASA DRAGONES BLANCO TEQ',
  26: 'NAVIGATOR CAB NAPA VALLEY',
  27: 'DONOVAN-PARKE PINOT NOIR',
  28: 'TOQUES CLOCHERS CREMANT',
  29: 'JAMESON IRISH WHISKEY',
  30: 'HENNESSY VS COGNAC 750ML',
  31: 'ATHENAEUM CAB SAUV NAPA',
  32: 'ENCORE PINOT NOIR MONTEREY',
  33: 'ABSOLUT VODKA',
  34: 'DON JULIO BLANCO TEQ',
  35: 'CROWN ROYAL CANDN WH 1.75',
  36: 'BUCCANEER CABERNET',
  37: 'NAVIGATOR NAPA SAUVIGNON BLANC',
  38: 'UNRULY DARK RED WINE',
  39: 'CARNEROS CREEK CHARDONNAY RSV'},
 'Pallets': {0: 33,
  1: 22,
  2: 22,
  3: 22,
  4: 22,
  5: 22,
  6: 22,
  7: 22,
  8: 22,
  9: 11,
  10: 11,
  11: 11,
  12: 11,
  13: 11,
  14: 11,
  15: 11,
  16: 11,
  17: 11,
  18: 11,
  19: 11,
  20: 14,
  21: 14,
  22: 14,
  23: 14,
  24: 7,
  25: 7,
  26: 7,
  27: 7,
  28: 7,
  29: 7,
  30: 7,
  31: 7,
  32: 7,
  33: 7,
  34: 7,
  35: 7,
  36: 7,
  37: 7,
  38: 7,
  39: 7}}
```

Comment: Could you provide the data in a way that can be easily used to reproduce the dataframes in the examples? Try `to_dict` on the pandas dataframe object

Comment: Done! I added Top 35 warehouse locations and their cumulative pallet capacity and Top 40 products with their demands in pallets.

Comment: In my opinion, this use case may not be appropriate for a dataframe alone, due to the logic required to allocate this way. You may want to try to represent the rows of this data as collections of objects (class instances) and perform custom logic that way. You could create a dataframe of the result after the fact for reporting. Read up on architecture patterns like Domain Driven Design. There's also lots of youtube videos on it. Here's a Medium post that hits the high points of it: https://medium.com/microtica/the-concept-of-domain-driven-design-explained-3184c0fd7c3f

Comment: Thank you! I will explore that. I was thinking to just extract the demand from the demand df, put it into a list and then run a loop somehow over the location df and add a new column there. Afterwards, I would cross reference the demand index to the SKU list.

Comment: Easier said than done I'm afraid. It looks to me like you'd need to keep track of at least available pallet qtys by location and remaining demand once assignments have been made by-line. The logic to make this work could get complicated. Plus, looping over DataFrames in this way is slow and inefficient. They're optimized for set-like operations and analysis, meaning operations that can be applied in parallel to the entire set of rows/columns

Comment: That makes sense :'( I will explore your suggestions above.